# lost formating on one page

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

Formating on one page is broken, namely in header part there is missing one parameter (word) and the columns looks differently as shows the picture bellow.
How can I correct the formating?

[The script can be found here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-tex-friends/58218#58218) and here is [full compilable example with pictures (37MB) of letter M](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qkfnirjsd7b75i2/dictionary_m_compilable.zip).
On page 22 appears lost formating. In zip files can be view also log files from compilation.

[image: picture]

Comment: I am pretty sure that your linked minimal example is not really minimal.

Comment: Yes. Plus the example is not complete, because the behaviour appears only in rare cases (fx. not in letters N, O etc.). We need to search for general ideas that can cause such behaviour in formating.

Comment: Without an compilable MWE I think it is very hard, I guess impossible to help you. First of all the pictures are missing. Then there could be an encoding problem, because for example I never used icelandic or czech (could be a problem if the language is not installed ...). Can you provide a compilable MWE, for example as a `zip` file (to make sure the encoding is right, to contain all pictures (you can change them to ìmage-example-a.jpg from package `MWE`), to keep your directory strukture or create one complete `tex` file) ...

Comment: I have added compilable files with log files. Thank you for attention.

Comment: I have observed that problem appear when there is in use either `{\devision{{\ding{96}}}}` or simply `\devision` command.

Comment: This questions needs to be reformatted. Please make the first few lines of the question a meaningful text which explains your problem, not "Find here the MW. Update: Here the full MWE.". These lines appear on overview pages and should also give a reader a good first impression. Also, "Update" or "Edit" headlines are unwanted here. Please simply edit your question to a new version which reflects the new content. Older versions can be viewed using the question history.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `floatrow` package is monkeying with the output routine in some incompatible way.

If you comment out these lines:

```
\usepackage{floatrow}
\DeclareFloatFont{footnotesize}{\footnotesize}% "scriptsize" is defined by floatrow, "tiny" not
\floatsetup[table]{font=footnotesize}
```

then the problem goes away, apparently without causing any other issues to your far-from-minimal testcase. If you do in fact need floatrow then I suggest to spend some effort to make a true minimal testcase (eliminate all the packages not needed from the preamble, etc) and send it to the floatrow author.

Comment: Thank you. I will observe more carefully the final result while adding new code to already made script. Later when I start adding tables with declentions I discover the issue with `floatrow`.